# New function that divides two columns based on a condition

Tags: python, division, calculated-columns

I 100% know I'm doing this wrong and the syntax is messed up but could use some help.

My last line of code is fine (es_rl['percent_complete'] = es_rl['Achieved']/es_rl['Goal']) BUT the kids can achieve more than the goal and I don't want to create a percent that is higher than 1. I attempted my hand at writing a function that would only divide the two columns based on the 'Achieved' column and wanted to pass the result by row into 'percent_complete'. Is this possible?

I'm pulling the data using sqlalchemy, so maybe there is a better solution using just sql. I just want to get better at python. Thanks in advance.

Edit, trying to use the min function. Getting a ValueError.

```
es_rl['percent_complete'] = min(es_rl['Achieved']/es_rl['Goal'], 1)

Data columns (total 5 columns):
scholar_id    12243 non-null int64
Goal          12243 non-null float64
Achieved      11263 non-null float64
GoalYear      12243 non-null int64
GoalWeek      12243 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(3)
```

Comment: `def es_rl['percent_complete']():` is not a valid way to declare a function at all.

Comment: I didn't think so....

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) to ensure your percent never goes above `1`?

```
es_rl['percent_complete'] = min(es_rl['Achieved']/es_rl['Goal'], 1)
```

**UPDATE**: You should've told us you're working with Pandas dataframes. Then you should use [`pandas.Series.clip()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html), e.g.:

```
es_rl['percent_complete'] = (es_rl['Achieved'] / es_rl['Goal']).clip(0, 1)
```

or

```
es_rl['percent_complete'] = es_rl['Achieved'].clip(0, es_rl['Goal']) / es_rl['Goal']
```

Comment: I get a ValueError, "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: What are the types of `es_rl['Achieved']` and `es_rl['Goal']`?

Comment: One is a float and one an int. EDIT: sorry they are both floats

Comment: I don't think the error lies in this line of code then.  Can you post your updated code?

Comment: @GregHodgson - where are you getting those elements from? What does `print(type(es_rl))` and `print(type(es_rl['Archived']))` produce?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> for es_rl and <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> for the achieved column

Answer (score 0):

If you're pulling the data from SQLAlchemy you could use a Case statement:

-Assuming your table is called Scholar

```
    def case_percent_complete():
        return case([((Scholar.Achieved / Scholar.Goal) > 1, 1), ],
                    else_=Scholar.Achieved / Scholar.Goal).label('percent_complete')

    results = session().query(Scholar.scholar_id
                                Scholar.Goal
                                Scholar.Achieved
                                Scholar.GoalYear
                                Scholar.GoalWeek,
                                case_percent_complete).\
            all()
```